# Why guava's Iterables.filter wants superclass in predicate?

Tags: java, guava

Why guava's `Iterables.filter` wants superclass in predicate?

```
public static <T> Iterable<T> filter(final Iterable<T> unfiltered, final Predicate<? super T> predicate)
```

Could you show me how I can filter objects of custom class ? I tried this

I tried this

```
Iterator<TaskSchedule> it = tsp.getAllItems(getCustomerId(), "getId", filter);

com.google.common.collect.Iterables.filter(it, new Predicate<Object>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Object input)
    {
        return false;
    }
});
```

which fails with following compilation error. I'm confused.

> Error:(132, 44) java:
>   C:\work\sideprojects\zzzz\SVN\inlineschedule-feature\test\cucumber\java\zzzz\com\zzz\cucumber\DBTestDriver.java:132:
>   cannot find symbol symbol  : method
>   filter(java.util.Iterator,>) location: class
>   com.google.common.collect.Iterables

I'm using JDK6

Comment: you might want to use some real type for the predicate (not Object)

Comment: @RC. `Predicate<Object>` is fine for the type if it only ever returns `false`. =) A predicate that always returns false worse for every type of object!

Comment: @ColinD `Predicates` has a `alwaysFalse()` :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your compilation error is due to the fact that you're passing an `Iterator` to `Iterables.filter`, which expects an `Iterable` as its first argument. You want `Iterators.filter`.

It's unrelated to your actual problem, but since you asked: `Iterables.filter` takes a `Predicate<? super T>` so that you can, for example, use a `Predicate<Object>` to filter a `List<String>`. If the predicate can handle some supertype of the type you want to filter, you can use that predicate.